# MPMediaItemPropertyTitle with MPMediaPlayer and Podcast causes Fatal Error

Tags: swift3, ios10, mpmediaplayercontroller

My MPMediaplayer is working pretty well for Music, but when I start working with Podcasts things are different.

I'm trying to get two things:
1) The name the Podcast Title ("This American Life")
2) The Episode Title ("My Holiday")

This line of code works fine to get the Podcast Title:

```
let podTitle:String = (myMP.nowPlayingItem?.podcastTitle)!
```

However this line should get the Episode Title:

```
let episode:String = myMP.nowPlayingItem?.value(forProperty: "MPMediaItemPropertyTitle") as! String
```

but causes a crash with this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How can I get the Episode Title for a given Podcast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPMediaItemPropertyTitle` is not the string property key; it is the name of a constant whose *value* is the property key. So, where you have

```
let episode:String = 
  myMP.nowPlayingItem?.value(forProperty: "MPMediaItemPropertyTitle") as! String
```

...remove the quotation marks:

```
let episode:String = 
  myMP.nowPlayingItem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as! String
```

I think what you are doing is still very foolish (you are asking to crash), but at least this way you stand a chance of success. What I do is actually more like this:

```
let temp = myMP.nowPlayingItem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
let episode = temp as? String ?? ""
```

That way you always end up with a string, which may be empty if there's a problem, and you won't crash.

Comment: It was the quotes that really got me - I'm pretty sure you need them in ObjC so I thought I also had to use them in Swift. Thanks!

Comment: You don't "need them in ObjC". This is about the MediaPlayer framework, not what language you use.